# How does openfaas solve the time zone problem of the container in the pod？

Tags: kubernetes, serverless, openfaas

I am currently deploying [openfaas](https://docs.openfaas.com/) on my local virtual machine's [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) cluster. I found that the time zone of the container started after publishing the function is inconsistent with the host machine. How should I solve this problem?

```sh
[root@k8s-node-1 ~]# date
# Host time
2021年 06月 09日 星期三 11:24:40 CST
[root@k8s-node-1 ~]# docker exec -it 5410c0b41f7a date
# Container time
Wed Jun  9 03:24:40 UTC 2021
```

Comment: I know nothing of OpenFaaS but I assume it's probably not doing anything special and the timezone inside the container is based on the `/etc/localtime` symlink like usual in Linux. Basically all container images will use UTC for that, most don't bother installing the tzdata files to save space. 11AM CST (UTC+8) is the same as 3AM UTC so that's entirely consistent.

Comment: Yes,This question should be considered based on the container, nothing about openfaas, thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

As **@coderanger** pointed out in the comments section, the timezone difference is not related to `OpenFaaS`.
It depends on the image you are using, most of the images use `UTC` timezone.
Normally this shouldn't be a problem, but in some special cases you may want to change this timezone.

As described in this [article](https://bobcares.com/blog/change-time-in-docker-container/), you can use the `TZ` environment variable to set the timezone of a container (there are also other ways to change the timezone).

If you have your own `Dockerfile`, you can use the [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) instruction to set this variable:
**NOTE:** The `tzdata` package has to be installed in the container for setting the `TZ` variable.

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM nginx:latest
RUN apt-get install -y tzdata
ENV TZ="Europe/Warsaw"

$ docker build -t mattjcontainerregistry/web-app-1 .
$ docker push mattjcontainerregistry/web-app-1
$ kubectl run time-test --image=mattjcontainerregistry/web-app-1
pod/time-test created

$ kubectl exec -it time-test -- bash
root@time-test:/# date
Wed Jun  9 17:22:03 CEST 2021
root@time-test:/# echo $TZ
Europe/Warsaw
```

Comment: I will try your method.

Comment: I solved this problem under this way, thanks again